# Auto generated coupon in M2. 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2

I am trying to create auto generated coupon codes for a specific rule programmatically. But facing problems continuously. Can you please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

```
    use Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap;
    require __DIR__ . '/../app/bootstrap.php';

    $bootstrap = Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);

    $obj = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();

    $state = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\State');
    $state->setAreaCode('frontend');
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 


    $rule_id = 11 ;
    $rule=$objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Rule')->load($rule_id); 
    $isactive = $rule->getIsActive(); 

    if($isactive){

        $expirationDate = strtotime("+30 day");
        $code ="FEOMCEE12";
        $coupon = $objectManager->create('Magento\SalesRule\Model\Coupon');        
        $coupon->setId(null)->setRuleId($rule_id)->setType(1)->setCode($code)->save();

    }
```